# MacOS: change @rpath to @executable_path with install_name_tool - app crash

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I use QT Creator with QT5.6 and have a sucessfully compiled app which run without issues on my Mac. 
To run this app on another Mac i use:

```
otool -L eMark-qt.app/Contents/MacOS/eMark-qt
```

Result:

```
...
@rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.3)
@rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.3)
...
```

now i have copied the QtGui.framework to eMark.app

```
cp -RL /Users/rumhocker/Qt5.6.3/5.6.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework /Users/Rumhocker/Downloads/eMark-master/eMark-Qt.app/Contents/Frameworks
```

after run

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Framework/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui eMark-Qt.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
```

and

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui eMark-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/eMark-Qt
```

the app crash on my Mac.
I dont know why. Are my commands right? Any idea about my problem?
Here you can found the error.log
https://pastebin.com/nYC3dLjR

Please have a look at line 71 there is the new location from QtGui.framework. In line 70, 72, 73 you can see that i dont touch the other frameworks with Install_name_tool at this moment.

Comment: Show the details of the crash. Did you compile your app with the `-headerpad_max_install_names` linker option?

Comment: I have edit my post and add the crash report.

Comment: According to the list of binary images in the crash report, the QtGui.framework is being loaded twice from two different locations. Perhaps there are interdependencies among the various Qt frameworks and you're not correcting them all.